# What attribute's are appropriate for log-in credentials

Tags: php, html, web

I'm currently working on a school project to create a quiz program (local-host) to assess students based on their marks on the quiz. So in that project's database, I have a "student" table and also a "student_name" table. I would have put it in the same table but my teacher told me to put it into two different tables as a normalization step to reach 3nf (getting rid of "transitional functions")? Below are the pictures of my tables: (Sorry, it's in Malay)
["murid"(student) table <no_kp_murid = "student's IC number"> <katalaluan = "password">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPOYU.png)
["nama_murid"(student_name) table <email_murid = "student's email"> <nama_murid = 'student's name>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dG07G.png)

So the problem is in the login page. Currently I'm using a "no_kp_murid"(IC number) - "katalaluan"(password) combination to log-in. So it logs in fine, but in the main_menu I'd like to display the "nama_murid"(student's name) attribute. The problem is, it displays the first student name registered and not the actual student-that-logged-in's name. Here's my code:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 include ('sambungan.php');

 if (isset($_POST['no_kp']))
 {
  $no_kp = $_POST['no_kp'];
  $katalaluan = $_POST['katalaluan'];
  $sql_nama_murid = 'select * from nama_murid';
  $return = mysqli_query($sambungan , $sql_nama_murid);
  $nama_murid = mysqli_fetch_array($return); // isytihar $nama_murid sbg pewakil table nama_murid
  $sql_murid = 'select * from murid';
  $result = mysqli_query($sambungan , $sql_murid);
  $jumpa = FALSE;
  while($murid = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
    if($murid['no_kp_murid'] == $no_kp && $murid['katalaluan'] == $katalaluan)
    {
        $jumpa = TRUE;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $no_kp;
        $_SESSION['nama_murid'] = $nama_murid['nama_murid'];//this'd be where the error is
        $_SESSION['status'] = 'murid';
        header('Location: utama_murid.php');
        break;
    }
   }
if($jumpa == FALSE)
{
 $sql_guru = "select * from guru";
 $result = mysqli_query($sambungan , $sql_guru);
 while($guru = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
     if($guru['no_kp_guru'] == $no_kp && $guru['katalaluan'] == $katalaluan)
       {
         $jumpa = TRUE;
         $_SESSION['username'] = $guru['no_kp_guru'];
         $_SESSION['nama_guru'] = $guru['nama_guru'];
         $_SESSION['status'] = 'guru';
         header('Location: utama_guru.php');
         break;
       }
   }
}
else
    echo "<script>alert('Kesalahan pada username atau password');
          window.location = 'login.php'</script> ";
}?>

 <title>Kuizrep - Log Masuk</title>
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='form.css'>

 <body>
    <div class="login">
      <img src="Logo%20Kuizrep.png" />
      <form class='login' action = 'login.php' method = 'post'>
        <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="no kad pengenalan" required = '' name = 'no_kp'/>
        <input class="input" type="password" placeholder="katalaluan" required = '' name = 'katalaluan' />
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button class = 'butang' type="submit"> Login </button>
      </form>
      <br>
      <centre><a href="signup.php">Pengguna Baharu?</a></centre>
     </div>
```

Any suggeesion's on what log-in credential combination I could use? I thought of putting the primary key of "murid"(student) table into the "nama_murid"(student's name) table so that I could use WHERE on he SQL query for calling the student's name but then I'd have to mess up my relationships and then I'd have to alter my other php codes in signup page etc. I'd really not have to do that. Any easier alternatives? Oh yeah, I code using html, and php and myphpadmin server. So no js pls. If you want any translations you can ask me I'll translate them.

"P.S: Sorry everything's in Malay and sorry if my code's messy. I'm a newbie"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a few errors that I found in your code. First of all, the student name table (nama_murid) needs to have a foreign key. In this case, the nama_murid table needs to have student_id similar to the murid table.

Your new nama_murid table should look like this:-

no_kp_murid (Student Id) ---- email_murid (Student email) ---- nama_murid (Student Name)

Here no_kp_murid is the foreign key that would relate the student login table to the student name table.

Regarding the code, there is an easier way to achieve what you want.

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    include ('sambungan.php');
    if(isset($_POST['no_kp']){
        $no_kp = $_POST['no_kp'];
        $katalaluan = $_POST['katalaluan'];
        $query = "select * from nama_murid where no_kp_murid='".$no_kp."' && katalaluan='".$katalaluan."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($sambungan , $query);

         if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                  $jumpa = TRUE;
                  $_SESSION['username'] = $no_kp;
                  $query_new = "select * from nama_murid where no_kp_murid ='".$no_kp."'";
                  $result_new = mysqli_query($sambungan , $query_new);
                  if ($result_new->num_rows > 0) {
                      while($row_new = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_new)) {
                          
                           $_SESSION['nama_murid'] = $row_new['nama_murid'];
                      }
                  }
                  $_SESSION['status'] = 'murid';
                  header('Location: utama_murid.php');
                  break;
              }
         }
    }
?>
```

You can either edit the rest of the code to follow a similar style or leave it as it is.

Comment: Yes thank you for your reply. I thought of this method but there are a few problems:

1) If I make the no_kp_murid as primary key, then I wouldn't be able to put AUTO_INCREMENT attribute on it.
2) This method would force me to alter my relationships in my database and then altering my other pages 

But thank you so much for your effort. I'll do this method if there are no other alternatives

Comment: I don't understand the first point. Why wouldn't you be able to make the Primary key an auto-increment? I am not sure if I misunderstand your point.

Comment: Oh because the IC (identification card) number can't be auto incremented. In Malaysia, it's 12 digits unique to every citizen. Plus, if the IC number is made as the primary key. Wouldn't that slow down my system when there are many users as the computer needs to compute alot of digits?

Comment: If you're against the idea of making it a primary key, that is alright as well. Since the IC number is supposed to be unique for each student, you can still add it to the second table. But, it is important that there should be a common column between the two tables. If there is no relation between the two tables, it would be difficult to fetch the data based on the login credentials only.

Comment: Yes...that would help. Thank you alot for your help. Appreciate it